# Post Request is not working, error showing "cannot post /addstudent/add"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, post

This is the post request I want to send but it is not working. I tried working with it in Postman as well as using forms but the error says ***"cannot POST /addstudent/add"***. Below is the code.

This is the JScode: I am using express and using it to post it in MongoDB.

```
app.post('/addstudent/add', function(req, res){
db.collection('students').insertOne(req.body, function(error, result){
    if(error)
        throw error;
    res.json(result);
    console.log("New student Successfully Added!");
    })
})
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="formdiv">
        <form action="/addstudent/add" method="POST"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Student Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Student Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Email" name="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Phone Number" name="Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Age</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Age" name="Age">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the whole JS code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoDB = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var hbs = require('hbs');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded());

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
var db;

mongoDB.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, 
function(error, client){
    if(error)
        throw error;
    db = client.db('attainu');
});

app.get('/instructors', function(req, res){
    res.render('instructor.hbs');
})

app.get('/students', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.hbs');
})

app.post('/addstudent/add', function(req, res){
    db.collection('students').insertOne(req.body, function(error, result){
        if(error)
            throw error;
        res.json(result);
        console.log("New student Successfully Added!");
    })
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: show your root `js` file

Comment: i have uploaded the whole JS file

Comment: how are you starting your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoDB = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var hbs = require('hbs');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));

//Add this line
 app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json())

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
var db;

 mongoDB.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, 
 function(error, client){
if(error)
    throw error;
db = client.db('attainu');
  });

 app.get('/instructors', function(req, res){
 res.render('instructor.hbs');
})

app.get('/students', function(req, res){
   res.render('index.hbs');
});

app.post('/addstudent/add', function(req, res){
    db.collection('students').insertOne(req.body, function(error, result){
    if(error)
        throw error;
    res.json(result);
    console.log("New student Successfully Added!");
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running at ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your same code as given above, every thing works fine. I have made no changes to the code. Data were being posted and successfully saved in database. The result is shown in the following image:

[image: screenshot of response shown in browser debugger console]